# Parse error in instantiating component-unexpected PORT

Tags: vhdl

I'm completely new to VHDL and I've been trying to solve the errors but cannot overcome this parse error when instantiating a component. As I use "port map" it says:

> **"ERROR:HDLParsers:164 - "D:/FPGA/correlation_1/corr_1.vhd" Line 89. parse error, unexpected PORT, expecting OPENPAR or TICK or LSQBRACK**
>   "

Here's the code:

```
component cmux_m1 
        port (ar,ai : in std_logic_vector( N-1 downto 0);
                br,bi : in std_logic_vector( N-1 downto 0);
                pr,pi : out std_logic_vector( N+N downto 0)
               );
    end component;
```

and the instantiation:

```
cmult_unit : cmux_m1
                    port map(ar=>xr, ai=>xi, br=>yr, bi=>yi, pr=>temr_0, pi=>temi_0);
```

thanks in advance.

sharing more codes:

```
entity corr_1 is

    generic( N : integer := 4;   -- N is the width of each input symbpl of the signals
                M : integer := 4);  -- M is the length of chosen parts of the signals to be correlated 

    port( clk : in std_logic;
            xr,xi : in std_logic_vector( N-1 downto 0);  -- real and imaginary N_bit symbol of the first signal
            yr,yi : in std_logic_vector( N-1 downto 0);  -- real and imaginary N_bit symbol of the second signal
            rr_0 : out std_logic_vector(N+N+2 downto 0); -- real part of the output with lag=0
            ri_0 : out std_logic_vector(N+N+2 downto 0); -- imaginary part of the output with lag=0
            rr_1 : out std_logic_vector(N+N+2 downto 0); -- real part of the output with lag=1
            ri_1 : out std_logic_vector(N+N+2 downto 0)  -- imaginary part of the output with lag=1
            );

end corr_1;

architecture hard_arch of corr_1 is
    signal Nyi,Cyi : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);                         --signals used to conjugate the second signal
    signal yi_c : signed(N-1 downto 0);                                      --signals used to conjugate the second signal
    signal yr_d,yi_d : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);                      --delayed signals used to do correlation with lag=1
    signal temr_0,temi_0,temr_1,temi_1 : std_logic_vector(N+N downto 0); --midterm signals for accumulator
    signal Srr_0,Srr_1,Sri_0,Sri_1 : signed(N+N+2 downto 0);             --midterm signals for accumulator
    signal counter_0 : integer range 0 to M;                             --counter with initial value of 0
    signal counter_1 : integer range 0 to M;                            --counter with initial value of 0  


-- component declaration (as we are using complex multiplier)
    component cmux_m1 
        port (ar,ai : in std_logic_vector( N-1 downto 0);
                br,bi : in std_logic_vector( N-1 downto 0);
                pr,pi : out std_logic_vector( N+N downto 0)
               );
    end component;      
begin

-- conjugating process using two's complement for the imaginary part of the second input signal
    process(clk)
        begin
            Nyi<= not yi;
            yi_c<=signed(Nyi);
            if rising_edge(clk) then
                Cyi<=std_logic_vector(yi_c + 1);                            --now conjugated signal is ready to be used 
            end if;
    end process;

-- delaying our second signal to prepare for correlation with lag=1 
    process(clk)
        begin
            if rising_edge(clk) then
                yr_d<=yr;
                yi_d<=Cyi;
            end if;
    end process;    

-- calculating correlation with lag=0
    process(clk)
        begin
            Srr_0<=(others=>'0');
            Sri_0<=(others=>'0');
            if counter_0 < M then
                if rising_edge(clk) then
                    cmult_unit : cmux_m1    
                    port map(ar=>xr, ai=>xi, br=>yr, bi=>Cyi, pr=>temr_0, pi=>temi_0);
                    Srr_0<= signed(temr_0) + Srr_0;
                    Sri_0<= signed(temi_0) + Sri_0;
                    counter_0<= counter_0 + 1;
                    rr_0<=std_logic_vector(Srr_0);
                    ri_0<=std_logic_vector(Sri_0);
                end if;
            elsif counter_0=M then
                Srr_0<=(others=>'0');
                Sri_0<=(others=>'0');
                rr_0<=(others=>'0');
                ri_0<=(others=>'0');
            end if;     
    end process;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I cannot see anything wrong with your component instantiation, which suggests that the error is elsewhere. When asking a question on Stack Overflow, it nearly always helps to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then someone who is trying to help you can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm sharing more codes to get help and it's going to calculate correlation. of course if it works :)

Comment: HDLPARSERS:164 is an XST error code reporting an unexpected token during syntactical analysis here the reserved word port which can only appear in either one of a port clause in an entity or component declaration, a block header, or in a port map aspect in a component instantiation, block header or binding indication. None of these are found in sequential statements. A component instantiation is a concurrent statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate your component inside (an `if` statement inside) a process. That does not mean anything. A component is (effectively) a lump of hardware. When you instantiate it, it must always exist. You cannot instantiate a component inside a process (or `if` statement) any more than you can have a chip magically appear and disappear on a PCB.

Components must be instantiated between `begin` and `end architecture`.

Comment: GREAT THANKS. Errors are gone :)

Comment: Or in a sequence of statements which would also rule out subprograms as well as process statements.